# Is there a way to include an ESM only package via require?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a node dependency that is included in version 2 with require. Now with version 3 the library can only be included with import.

> Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module

But my script uses require.

Is there a way to include an ESM only package via require?

Comment: No, there's not. Switch your code to ES modules as well, or stay with version 2.

Comment: I was afraid of that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use dynamic import for this purpose but it's better to use the version that supports CommonJs unless you are using ESM itself

`const thePackage = import('the-package');`

Answer (score 0):

Yes; I've built the [fix-esm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fix-esm) library for this purpose. It works basically by transparently converting ESM exports to CJS exports.